# Angular Bootstrap for *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using `*ngFor` to get some objects and i want to display them on a webpage.I'm using `<div class col-sm-4>` for every object.I should have 3 on a row ,but i still have 12 objects and I can't understand why.

HTML:

```
<div class="display row" *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <p>Field name: {{field.name}}</p>
    <p>Crop Type: {{field.Crop}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{field.Description}}</p>
    <button class = "modify">Modify</button>
    <button class="view" onclick="document.getElementById('ViewAll').style.display = 'block'">View all</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.display{
    display:inline-block;
    border: 5px solid #1976d2;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
    border-radius: 15px;
    
}
```

Comment: I believe that the outer div is in loop. So, it is being rendered for each object as a new div.

Comment: I tried adding the 'col-sm-4' to the outer div but still doesn't work

Comment: Try having *ngFor in inner div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *ngFor is in outer div, it is rendering new row for each object. Keep it inner div and remove display in css.

```
<div class="display row" >
  <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <p>Field name: {{field.name}}</p>
    <p>Crop Type: {{field.Crop}}</p>
    <p>Description: {{field.Description}}</p>
    <button class = "modify">Modify</button>
    <button class="view" onclick="document.getElementById('ViewAll').style.display = 'block'">View all</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

in css:

```
.display{
border: 5px solid #1976d2;
padding: 50px;
margin: 20px;
box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
border-radius: 15px;
```

}